# If $p(x)<1,$ then why does there exists $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $\alpha^{-1}x\in M$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

**Definition:** Given that $E$ is a normed linear space. Let $M\subseteq E$ be an open, convex set with $0\in M.$ For all $x\in E$, define

\begin{align} p(x)=\inf\{\alpha>0:\,\alpha^{-1}x\in M \} \end{align} 
Then, $p$ is called a guage of $M$.

**My question:** I am going through a proof which claims that if $p(x)<1,$ then there exists $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $\alpha^{-1}x\in M.$

**MY TRIAL:**  From my own understanding, for fixed $x\in E$
 \begin{align} p(x)=\inf\{\alpha>0:\,\alpha^{-1}x\in M \} \end{align}
if and only if $\forall\,\epsilon>0,\;\exists\,\alpha_{\epsilon}>0$ such that 
\begin{align} p(x)\leq \alpha_{\epsilon}<p(x)+\epsilon\,. \end{align} 
Please, can anyone explain why the claim if $p(x)<1,$ then there exists $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $\alpha^{-1}x\in M$ holds?

Answer (score 1):

Since $p(x)<1$, take $p(x)<\alpha<1$. By definition of p: $\alpha ^{-1} x \in M$.

Note that an interesting question is proving that if $p(x)<1$ then x is and *internal point* of M.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and would love to share:

If $p(x)<1$ for a fixed $x\in E$, then by Archimedean principle, there exists $\alpha\in (0,1)$ such that $p(x)<\alpha<1$ and $\alpha^{-1}x\in M.$